# "machine" and "view" menu disappeared from guest window of virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox

I was fooling around with the diefferent display options and at some point, the machine and view menus disappeared from my guest window. I think it was after I switched from scale mode. I used host+C to switchc back but now some menus are missing (I can't say if they just "never came back", since I don't remember)
Now the menus of the guest window only show: file, input, devices and help.
I updated to 5.0.16 but it didn't work. (I am on a windows 10 host)

The menus seem fine on other guests though.
Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance. Screen capture:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

click <kbd>Right CTRL</kbd> & <kbd>Home</kbd> buttons at same time to bring up the menu, you can change the display from there, change it to scaled, then hit the expander in the upper right hand corner, it should expand your guest into the whole VBOx window, with the menu options on the top bar, and the other VBox stuff at the bottom right (disk, cd, monitor, usb, shared folders, and so on,,,)

Answer (score 2):

In the Linux Virtualbox you can right-click a context menu in any blank spot on the menubar (to the right of the "Help" menu for example) and then choose "Menu Bar Settings..." where you can enable/disable menu items.

Answer (score 2):

This is the only way which worked for me:

- Go to the settings of your VM
- Select "User Interface"
- Click each items to become light blue
- Tick the checkbox on the right of the item bar
- Also tick the 2 checkboxes below the item bar

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. Looks like it happened after I used the same virtual machine file in a recent version of VirtualBox in a Linux host. Now after booting back in Windows 7 host and using the old VirtualBox version I use here, the menu items are no longer there, and there is no option to restore it in this old version. None of the above solutions were of help for me, so I started trying to fix it myself and found this line:

```
<ExtraDataItem name="GUI/RestrictedRuntimeMenus" value="Machine,Devices,Debug"/>
```

in a file located in

```
C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\VirtualBox VMs\Windows 7 x64 SP1.vbox
```

(is in the same folder where your current .vdi file is).

I shut down the virtual machine, removed the aforementioned line and saved the file, and now the menu items are back.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one: <kbd>Host</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.

In your case that will mean <kbd>R Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).